# How to say "Wir haben viel Zeit" in past tense

Tags: tense, past-participle, past

How would you make this into the past tense?

Ex : Wir haben viel Zeit

Answer (score 2):

In German, there are normally two ways to express something in the past tense: *Präteritum* and *Perfekt*.

*Präteritum*: (We had a lot of time)

> Wir hatten viel Zeit.

*Perfekt*: (We have had a lot of time)

> Wir haben viel Zeit gehabt.

Haben is used here as a helper verb, and is similar to 'have' in the Perfekt case. Rules to form the past can easily be looked up.

Which you should use depends highly on the context and the verb in question. In general, it is better to use *Perfekt* for speaking and *Präteritum* for writing. However, in this case, I would use *Präteritum* in both cases because the verb *haben* is normally expressed this way. The verb *sein* is also this way. There are many exceptions and rules to go along with this, and it's better to learn them as you go until you're more comfortable with the concept.

Comment: Ok Thanks! I was confused because having two habens' seemed weird